# Finding the eigenvalue/vector of a Leslie Matrix and purpose of eigenvalue/vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, biology, population-dynamics

I am currently working on a population dynamics model, in which I have to model the population growth of an animal with the survival rate and fecundity rate.

I have set-up a 6 x 6 Matrix below:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1.4 & 1.6 & 1.1 & 0.3 \\
0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0       \\
0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0       \\
0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0 & 0 & 0       \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0       \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0       \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Initial Population Matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1150\\
1000\\
975 \\
750\\
450\\
200\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am struggling to calculate the eigenvalue/eigenvector and understand what exactly the eigenvalue/eigenvector indicates and what it can be used for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).